# How to disable Logback file appender's logs

Tags: java, logging, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I have rolling file appender set-up as follows

```
  <appender name="ACCESS_S3" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/opt/mycompany/${application}-server/access/localwebserver.extended.log
    </file>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy
            class="com.mycompnay.logback.core.rolling.S3TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/opt/mycompany/${application}-server/access/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        <configBucketKey>com.mycompany.log.bucket</configBucketKey>
        <s3FolderName>
            ${application}/access/${servername}_
        </s3FolderName>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${encoderPattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
```

But I get log from appender itself about file uploading, renaming etc on the console like ->

```
INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1481886288 - Uploading /opt/mycompnay/myapp-server/access/2018-04-09-1542.log
```

I want to disable logs like above, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

decrease logging level for TimeBasedRollingPolicy class

```
<logger name="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy" 
   level="ERROR">
   <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_S3" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I tried following to supress all logs from classes under `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper` package but it doesn't work, do I need to reduce level for each class ? `<logger name="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper" level="ERROR">
  <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_S3" />
</logger>`

Comment: try with package ch.qos.logback.core.rolling    <logger name="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling" level="ERROR"> <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_S3" /> </logger>

Comment: alternative try with <logger name="com.mycompnay.logback.core.rolling" level="ERROR"> <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_S3" /> </logger>